# Is this gramatically correct? (with options)

Tags: grammar

Context: Class mate gave me a gift

> "A gift from my classmate. It is moments/things like these/this which make my heart grow fonder of XYZ school every day"

I'm wondering if I should use *moments* over *things* and *these* over *this*.

Comment: Is there a specific problem that you can see (or at least suspect)? 'A gift from my classmate.' being a sentence fragment? The choice of 'which' instead of 'that'?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it slightly differently:

> A gift from my classmate; it's times like these which make my heart grow fonder of Pheonix Tumbleweed High School everyday.

However, moments like these is just as acceptable. Here is a nice graph:

[image: NGrams]

Interestingly I would always say "these" - not sure why, and it should probably technically be "this" - it's only one event. However, you are saying "*All similar events to this one have X effect*", so there is a plurality there.

Recently (between 1986 and 1988) the two (these vs this) swapped over:

[image: NGrams2]

Click for a zoomed in view of the crossover.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be either moments or things. OP talks about his friend giving him a gift that makes him appreciate him school more. Hence, it should be 'moments' like receiving a gift or 'doing things' like giving a gift along with other similar occarances that makes  his heart grow fonder.